# Getting values from a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, tiles

This is my array:

```
private static int[][] map = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

I generate a tile map using this class:

```
public class Map {

public static final int CLEAR = 0;
public static final int STONE = 1;
public static final int GRASS = 2;
public static final int DIRT = 3;

public static final int WIDTH = 32;
public static final int HEIGHT = 24;

public static final int TILE_SIZE = 25;

private static int[][] map = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

Image air, grass, stone, dirt;

Random rand = new Random();

public Map() {

    /* default map */

    /*for(int y = 0; y < WIDTH; y++){
        map[y][y] = (rand.nextInt(2));
        System.out.println(map[y][y]);
    }*/

    for (int y = 18; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            map[x][y] = STONE;
        }

    }

    for (int y = 18; y < 19; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            map[x][y] = GRASS;
        }

    }

    for (int y = 19; y < 20; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            map[x][y] = DIRT;
        }

    }

    try {
        init(null, null);
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    render(null, null, null);

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    air = new Image("res/air.png");
    grass = new Image("res/grass.png");
    stone = new Image("res/stone.png");
    dirt = new Image("res/dirt.png");
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) {
    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            switch (map[x][y]) {
            case CLEAR:
                air.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case STONE:
                stone.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case GRASS:
                grass.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case DIRT:
                dirt.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean blocked(float x, float y) {
    return map[(int) x][(int) y] == STONE;
}

public static Rectangle blockBounds(int x, int y) {
    return(new Rectangle(map[0][x], map[y][0], 25, 25));
}}
```

I want to assign each tile a rectangle with this code(I know its wrong):

```
public static Rectangle blockBounds(int x, int y) {
    return(new Rectangle(map[0][x], map[y][0], 25, 25));
}
```

How do get the x and y coordinates of the tiles and put them into the rectangle code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using,

`private static int[][] map = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];`

to represent your map. So each`{x,y} of the map represent a point on your map. The constructor of Rectangle Class, Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) is used to Constructs a new Rectangle whose upper-left corner is specified as (x,y) and whose width and height are specified by the arguments of the same name. So I think this will work easily,

```
new Rectangle(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)
```

Also to use this constructor you have to start the navigation of your map from {0,0}

Comment: so my code should look like this? `public static Rectangle blockBounds(int x, int y) {
     return(new Rectangle(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE));
 }`

Comment: How would I go about actually doing the collision detecting though? I know you have to use .intersects, but how would I set up the method?

Comment: I dint get your question? You mean you wont to know weather the rectangular tile which you assigned t point is intersecting other points?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
new Rectangle(x * TILE_SIZE, Y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
```